# GNU make creating Docker container and using Image id

Tags: docker, makefile, gnu

I am trying to create a recipe that will execute my lint results inside my docker container, and copy the `results.xml` outside the container. Here is my recipe:

```
lint-results:
    docker build --target lint path_to_my_src_dir -t $(my_lint_image_tag)
    $(eval tmp_lint_container_id:=$(shell docker create $(my_lint_image_tag))) # This step seems to execute too quick
    @echo my lint constainer id is $(tmp_lint_container_id)
    docker cp $(tmp_lint_container_id):/usr/src/app/results.xml ./
    docker rm -v $(tmp_lint_container_id)
```

The problem I'm having is after it successfully creates the `$(my_lint_image_tag)` from the docker build and moves on to create the container. The first time around it errors out and the echoed output for `$(tmp_lint_container_id)` is blank, but if I run it again it works. It seems to only fail the first time around if initially, the image wasn't there, almost like it's running the `shell` command to quickly after the docker image is built.

Here a snippet if the output of the error:

```
Removing intermediate container a6f4eb8ac404
 ---> 01cb85644929
Successfully built 01cb85644929
Successfully tagged my-lint-image-1.1.1.1:latest
my lint constainer id is
docker cp :/usr/src/app/results.xml ./
must specify at least one container source
make: *** [lint-results] Error 1
```

Is there a way to ensure docker image is there before the `shell` command is ran?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pro Tip #1: If you are using `$(eval ..)` or `$(shell ...)` inside a recipe, you are almost invariably doing something wrong.

Use shell variables, not make variables, to hold values inside recipes.  Like this:

```
lint-results:
        docker build --target lint path_to_my_src_dir -t $(my_lint_image_tag)
        tmp_lint_container_id=$$(docker create $(my_lint_image_tag)) && \
        docker cp $$tmp_lint_container_id:/usr/src/app/results.xml ./ && \
        docker rm -v $$tmp_lint_container_id
```

Comment: "If you are using $(eval ..) or $(shell ...) inside a recipe, you are almost invariably doing something wrong." Could you please explain why it is bad using `$eval` or `$shell` inside a recipe?

Comment: First, the recipe is already running in a shell so `$(shell ...)` is at best redundant.  Second, `$(eval ...)` changes the _global state_ of make so running it in a recipe is at best misleading.  Those are good enough reasons.  But even more than that, from a practical standpoint, people are confused by expansion in recipes: make expands the _entire recipe_ before it starts to run it.